# Chef: undefined method `platform_version'

Tags: chef-infra

I'm getting an error message when chef_client is running recipes. As far, I've been able to figure out it's telling me that:

> undefined method `platform_version'

I've tried to perform the recipes wit a centos/7, version: `1611.01` and `1703.01`. Here you can see the complete trace:

```
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/living-development/recipes/default.rb
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default: NoMethodError
==> default: -------------
==> default: undefined method `platform_version' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000004f4f480>
==> default:
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default:   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mongodb3/recipes/package_repo.rb:26:in `from_file'
==> default:   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mongodb3/recipes/default.rb:20:in `from_file'
==> default:   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/living-development/recipes/mongodb.rb:9:in `from_file'
==> default:   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/living-development/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'
==> default:
==> default: Relevant File Content:
==> default: ----------------------
==> default: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mongodb3/recipes/package_repo.rb:
==> default:
==> default:  19:
==> default:  20:  pkg_major_version = node['mongodb3']['version'].to_f # eg. 3.0, 3.2
==> default:  21:
==> default:  22:  # Setup default package version attribute to install
==> default:  23:  pkg_version = node['mongodb3']['version']
==> default:  24:  case node['platform_family']
==> default:  25:    when 'rhel', 'fedora'
==> default:  26>>     pkg_version =  "#{node['mongodb3']['version']}-1.el#{node.platform_version.to_i}" # ~FC019
==> default:  27:      if node['platform'] == 'amazon'
==> default:  28:        pkg_version = "#{node['mongodb3']['version']}-1.amzn1" # ~FC019
==> default:  29:      end
==> default:  30:  end
==> default:  31:
==> default:  32:  # Setup default package repo url attribute for each platform family or platform
==> default:  33:  case node['platform']
==> default:  34:    when 'redhat', 'oracle','centos', 'fedora' # ~FC024
==> default:  35:      pkg_repo = "https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/#{pkg_major_version}/#{node['kernel']['machine'] =~ /x86_64/ ? 'x86_64' : 'i686'}"
==> default:
==> default: System Info:
==> default: ------------
==> default: chef_version=13.0.118
==> default: platform=centos
==> default: platform_version=7.3.1611
==> default: ruby=ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
==> default: program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=12132;start=09:52:48;
==> default: executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
==> default:
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:06+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:06+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 18 seconds
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:06+00:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 30b10346-fc52-4aac-86cd-f76ccd8e0576)
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:07+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:07+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:07+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `platform_version' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000004f4f480>
==> default: [2017-04-24T09:53:07+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Any ideas?

**WORK AROUND:**

```
config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    ...
    chef.version = '12.19.36'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We removed the method syntax for node attributes in Chef 13. The code needs to be updated to `node["platform_version"]`.

Comment: Is there any work around in order to solve it by now?

Comment: Sure, roll back to Chef 12. Chef 13 is very new and not all community cookbooks have updated.

Comment: I've not specified any special chef version. I'm guessing it's trying to get the latest stable version. Is there any way to specify it?

Comment: In kitchen add `require_chef_omnibus: 12` to the provisioner section. For production that depends on how you update things.

Comment: I'm using vagrant: `config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|...`